# c# webservice class response

Tags: c#, web-services

I have class:

```
    public class LoginResponse
    {
        public String SessionID { get; private set; }
        public DateTime? ActiveTo { get; private set; }

        public LoginResponse()
        {
        }

        public LoginResponse(String sessionID, DateTime? activeTo)
        {
            this.SessionID = sessionID;
            this.ActiveTo = activeTo;
        }
    }
```

And i want to return this class as webservice response:

```
[WebMethod]
        public LoginResponse Login(String login, String password)
        {
            return new LoginResponse("a", null);
        }
```

The class LoginResponse is in other dll. What must i do, because i got an error??

The errors told that i must using attribute WebMethodAttribute or change root type using XmlRootAttribute, because LoginResponse refers to method or type

Comment: Please add the error displayed at compile time.

Comment: what error *exactly* do you see?

Comment: described an error in the last line , because I have a message in Polish

Comment: Then type it in Polish ;) We are here too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution:

I must change function name from login :)
Now it's name is servicelogin and works fine :)

regards